# How to check whether MOD drive is working in Linux based system

Tags: linux

I have an issue with the Linux based computer which belongs to Hitachi MRI Medical Equipment. We replaced the [MOD drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto-optical_drive) (not CD or DVD) which was used to read MOD disks. After replacing the Drive I am not getting any response from the OS. I wanted to know how to check whether new MOD drive is operational in the Linux based system. I believe it will be mounted similar to a CDROM or DVD.

The Linux running in the computer is kind of some secure console but I can access to terminal while booting. I don't know whether I have root access or not.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like equipment which isn't really intended for DIY maintenance and which is not unlikely to only work with certified OEM replacement parts. I assume the operator manual has a section on running self-diagnostics, but you should probably contact the vendor or a certified technician...

Answer (score 2):

Your Linux based system will almost certainly be locked down tight to prevent misconfiguations and given that this is a medical device you should not expect to be able to throw just any hardware at it.

Your system will almost certainly have a support contract, you should ask the vendor which MOD Drives are compatible with their system and work with them to get where you want to go.